# How do you get both date and time from a PreparedStatement in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I am currently using `SELECT datetime FROM table1 WHERE condition=?` as the query and getting the ResultSet object, and I am using `rs.getDate()` and it is creating a Date object with no Time as part of it. Is it possible to get both the Date and the Time from the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getTimestamp()` should fetch you both the "date" and "time" part. Read the docs for `java.sql.Date` (which is returned by `getDate` and `java.sql.Timestamp` for knowing the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the date stored in one of the columns of the resultset obtained from the database, then you can use the `rs.getDate(columnIndex)` method.
You have to specify the index of the column which contains the date.
suppose your table is like this:

ID | name | date|

then you will have to use `rs.getDate(3)` 
[or may be `getDate(2)`, I am not sure if the column index starts from 0 or 1 ]